# Reemplazar <body onload>

Tags: javascript

En mi sitio tengo `<body id="kt_body" onload="funcionn()">` y antes de terminar el `</body>` tengo Jquery y mi archivo Javascript:

```
<script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/front.js"></script>
```

Que evidentemente llama a una función que tengo en `front.js`

```
function funcionn() {
  init(),
    $("#boton2").bind("click", function () {
      dos(document.console.texto.value, document.console.ejem.value);
    });
}
```

**Y quiero saber si hay otra forma de hacer eso mismo sin tener que usar el onload dentro del body?**

Quiero evitar malas prácticas (incrustar código Javascript en HTML) y que mi página sea lo más rápida posible.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu archivo front.js podrias usar:

```
    window.onload = function (){
        //tu función
    }
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cómo lo comentaron arriba, en un archivo Javascript alterno, coloqué:

```
window.onload = function (funcionn){
        init(),
    $("#boton2").bind("click", function () {
      dos(document.console.texto.value, document.console.ejem.value);
    });
    }
```

Y eliminé el `onload="funcionn()"` de mi `<body>`.

Con esos cambios mi página se ejecuta correctamente.